# Django_tables2: Split columns

Tags: django, split, formatting, django-tables2

I try to split cell with comma separated integers into n columns, but can't find how to do that in Django_tables2.

---

Source:
id |  Name  | Marks |
 1 |  Peter | 3,2,4 |
 2 |  Joe   | 4,4,4 |
Result:
id |  Name  |   Marks   |
 1 |  Peter | 3 | 2 | 4 |
 2 |  Joe   | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box by django-tables2.

A possible solution might be to render the 3 marks in different columns, with some `<th>` attribute and use some JavaScript to merge the header into one cell with `colspan="3"`.